# Global issues to set app = Flask(__name__)

Tags: python, flask

The situation is that I want to use the `app = Flask(__name__)` and the `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` in file `__init__.py` global

Running this app causes that the `@app.route('/drink/<id>')` is returning proper the Drinks from the database but when I select `@app.route('/')` return an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
```

when I add `app = Flask(__name__)` direct under the from import statements the file hello_there.html is found but than the
error:

```
KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'
```

so what I think is that setting the `app = Flask(__name__)` twice is overwriting  the database connection

I expected that setting those parameter in the `__init__.py` file was good enough for both but .

Any idea why the Database db is doing goof in the `__init__.py` file but not acting  normal for the template?

File_1: app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from Data import  app,db

@app.route('/')
 
def hello_there(name = None):
    return render_template("hello_there.html")

@app.route('/drink/<id>')
def get_drink(id):

    drink = Drink.query.get_or_404(id)
    return {"name": drink.name, "description": drink.description}
```

File_2: /Data/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

File_3: Drinks.py

```
from Data import  db, app

class Drink(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(120))

    def __repr_(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggest structure for you app is :

```
- my_app
-- static/
--- ...
-- templates/
--- hello_there.html
-- __init__.py
-- data.py
-- app.py
```

`__init__.py` : place you register all extension and config

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'
```

**data.py** : place only models

```
from . import db

class Drink(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(120))

    def __repr_(self):
        return self.name 

    @classmethod
    def get(id):
        data = cls.query.get_or_404(id)
        return data
```

**app.py** : my suggest change to **routes.py**, place for all endpoint

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from . import app 
from data import Drink

@app.route('/')
def hello_there(name = None): 
    return render_template("hello_there.html")

@app.route('/drink/<int:id>') 
def get_drink(id):
    drink = Drink.get(id)
    return {"name": drink.name, "description": drink.description}
```

more for flask structure you can check [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/?highlight=structure#larger-applications)

hopefully answer your question!

Comment: Thank you and yes I do have it like this but when I run this code  the@app.route('/drink/<int:id>')  routes works well but the render_template("hello_there.html")  runs in to an error:  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Comment: You need create hello_there.html inside templates folder. are you have created it ?

Comment: make it simple, just from . import db, and set your flask app to what the result ? check the answer, i have update it.

Comment: Yes all is the same as you suggested. The database returning drinks works proper but still complain about the missing html file. When I put app = Flask(__name__) in the app.py file it works! but it broke the database connection

Comment: you need migration for apply the database class. are done have migrate? if no, check this link https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html